# How to stop gdb from printing the full string and instead force it to print the individual bytes

Tags: c, string, debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering

gdb keeps showing me the full string stored in a register rather than the bytes even when I use x /b. I also noticed it just skips over every byte's address until it reaches the end of the string and all the other bytes that get printed are just empty strings.

what happens when I normally print value stored in the address in rbx
[image]

what happens when I try printing 16 bytes
[image]

as you can see the address jumps from 0xc42004df02 to 0xc42004df17
[image]

I can also print addresses individually
[image]

As you can see, there is no way for me to print individual bytes and all I get are strings. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Try `x/db` instead of `x/b`.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'll make sure to keep that in mind for future posts. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Hi ssbssa, this worked! However, I noticed that it only printed bytes as decimals. Fortunately, I was able to resolve my issue a little while back using x /x to convert the address value to hex and then did x /32x to print out 32 bytes. However, your solution made it a lot clearer to me how my fix actually worked! Rbx was holding a string so x /b was useless. In order to make x /b work, I had to convert it to hex with x /x. This intermediary step is exempt when using x /db, but if you want hex over decimal, you still need to do x /x and then x/32b. Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: You can use the `edit` button below your question to replace the links to pictures of text with the text itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.